# Flutter pressing the deviceback button doesn't do any actions while keyboard is open in bottomsheet

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am facing an issue in my Flutter app where I have a bottom sheet with a TextField. When the back button is pressed, I want to close the keyboard and unfocus the TextField. However, the TextField remains focused, even after the keyboard close. I have tried various solutions, including using WillPopScope, but none of them work as expected.

Infact, while textfield is open in bottomSheet, when the back button doesn't do any actions. How can I properly close the keyboard and unfocus the TextField when the back button is pressed within the bottom sheet?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setModalState) {
      return OnBackPressed(
        perform: () {
          print('The back button on the device was pressed');
          _focusNode.unfocus();
        },
        child: Container(
          // Bottom sheet content
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Add comments...',
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onEditingComplete: () async {
              _focusNode.unfocus();
              // Additional logic after editing is complete
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To Close keyboard programatically use **FocusManager**, it will close your keyboard and un-focus your textField.

```
FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
```

Use like this:

```
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async {
              if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
                //_focusNode.unfocus();
                FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
              } else {
                FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                Get.back();
              }

              return true;
            },
            child: StatefulBuilder(
                builder: (context, setModalState) {
                  return TextField(
                    focusNode: _focusNode,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Add comments...',
                    ),
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    onEditingComplete: () async {
                      _focusNode.unfocus();
                      // Additional logic after editing is complete
                    },
                  );
                }),
          );
        },
      );
```

check this gif:

[image]

Comment: hey jaimin, this is how i used it & not work
perform: () {
                                print(
                                    'The back button on the device was pressed');
                                if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
                                  // _focusNode.unfocus();
                                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus!.unfocus();
                                } else {
                                  _focusNode.unfocus();
                                  Get.back();
                                }
                              },

Comment: i have updated answer it is working i have checked.

Comment: the issue is if the keyboard is open in bottomsheet the u hit the back button it doesn't perform any action. but it closes the keyboard. nothing else. no print, unfocus, any action is triggered

Comment: can you please add this **OnBackPressed** custom widget code?

Comment: It's not a widget, it's a package. and it's not just that but the code doesn't work even with popscope.

Comment: it's strange bcoz with PopScope it is working fine check gif

Comment: i know it closes the keyboard. but extend the height of the bottomsheet and try displaying the focusnode.hasFocus. initially it's false. when u open the keyboard it switches to true. but when u peress back button then the keyboard closes but the focusnode still shows true. meaning it still has focus and still thinks the keyboard is open. Try that

Answer (score 0):

The answer is WillPopScope. It will prevent the page from being popped by the system. You'll still be able to use Navigator.of(context).pop().

```
  showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setModalState) {
      return OnBackPressed(
        perform: () {
          print('The back button on the device was pressed');
          _focusNode.unfocus();
        },
        child: new WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
child :Container(
          // Bottom sheet content
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Add comments...',
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onEditingComplete: () async {
              _focusNode.unfocus();
              // Additional logic after editing is complete
            },
          ),
        ),
);
      );
    });
  },
);
```

Comment: Yeah tried that but the issue is when keyboard is open while in bottomsheet and try to hit back button. and it closes the keyboard but it will not get triggered to perform the actions, like unfocusing.

Comment: Use _focusNode.unfocus();  keyboard here onWillPop: () async => false,

Answer (score -1):

```
showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (context) {
                  // Create a FocusNode to manage the focus of the TextField
                  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

                  return WillPopScope(
                    onWillPop: () async {
                      // Close the keyboard and unfocus the TextField
                      focusNode.unfocus();
                      return true;
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextField(
                            focusNode: focusNode,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Add comments...',
                            ),
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                            onEditingComplete: () {
                              focusNode.unfocus();
                            },
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 16),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Additional button logic
                            },
                            child: Text('Submit'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
```

Comment: the issue is it doesn't get triggered while keyboard is open in bottomsheet. it closes the keyboard but it doesn't unfocus

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try using WillPopScope widget.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        _focusNode.unfocus();
        return true;
      },
      child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setModalState) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNode,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Add comments...',
            ),
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onEditingComplete: () async {
              _focusNode.unfocus();
            },
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you've validated this content. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and become a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!